# Using a function from joomla plugin file

Tags: php, paypal, joomla

As stated in my question, how can i use the function which is inside joomla plugin folder from an external php file?

To be exact, it is under this patch "/plugins/system/rsfppayment/rsfppayment.php" and I want to use the function rsfp_afterConfirmPayment(). I pasted the code snippet below and this file is from rsForm Pro Paypal payment plugin.

```
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

/**
 * RSForm! Pro Payment Plugin
 */
class plgSystemRSFPPayment extends JPlugin
{
function rsfp_afterConfirmPayment($SubmissionId) {
        RSFormProHelper::sendSubmissionEmails($SubmissionId);
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have the plugin installed with the functionality, what rest do you want to be done ?

Comment: I want to use this function from the another webpage. Currently, I cannot call this class for unknow reason :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
require_once('/plugins/system/rsfppayment/rsfppayment.php');
$objplgSystemRSFPPayment = new plgSystemRSFPPayment();
$objplgSystemRSFPPayment->rsfp_afterConfirmPayment($submissionId);
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the path is correct and the value of $submissionId is valid.

Comment: I tried that way. But I cannot call the class. Everytime I call the class, I got 500 error and there is no error log for this. Please help.

Comment: Found the error. It was just inside the function that call the parameter of the requested url. Thank you anyway. :D

Answer (score 0):

Post the complete code then you use. The code of itoctopus is correct